# display none with acf checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i would like to allow admin to control a HTML section visabily.
so when admin check it, the section at frontend will be "display:none"
im using acf checkbox but can't seem to get it done.

would love for some help :)

tnx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: please provide some code, so we can check, how you are validating the checkbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an Option Page with ACF

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Then add your acf checkbox field to that option page then on your front end template use an if statement and inline CSS

```
<?php
if(get_field('field_name', 'option')){
    echo style="display:none";
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$style = '';
if(get_field('field_name', 'option')){
    $style = 'style="display:none"';
}
?>

<div <?php echo $style; ?>>Section to be hidden</div>
```

Comment: Tnx Paul. it doesn't seems to work. it's pring out the checkbox value rather the display non the div. does the acf checkbox must be set options page ?

Comment: Sorry my bad should be get_field(); instead of the the_field(); I've edited the answer. The checkbox can be on a page instead of on the options page but you won't need the 'option' in get field just get_field('field_name')

Comment: sorry for the hustle but i now i get white screen of death :) http://prntscr.com/heojv6  this is my code: <?php
$style = ''; if( get_field(); ('weekly_pr', 'option')){    $style = 'style="display:none"'; }
?>

<div <?php echo $style; ?>>Section to be hidden</div>

Comment: Working! my bad. Tnx :)

Comment: No problem can you accept my answer please?